# How to create timeout for Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Inputbox

Tags: c#, winforms, timeout

I am writing a sign in program. When a new user enters an ID for the first time it asks them for there first and last name using a Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Inputbox. I need to be able to timeout this Input Box after a minute and instead return an empty string if the user doesn't press OK by the end of the minute

```
string first;
string last;
first = Interaction.InputBox("What is your first name?", "First Name", "");
last = Interaction.InputBox("What is your last name?", "Last Name", "");
```

Comment: why do you need to time this out..? what if the user gets distracted and need to look away from the log in and or answer the phone? your design / approach seems a bit flawed unless there is some logical reason why you would want to do this

Comment: The user logs in using a bar code scanner. If the code is not recognized it prompts the user to create a new account. However the bar code scanner has a tendency to scan thin air ever 20ish minutes. If I was to leave this running all day the bar code scanner would register random non existing users if the window didn't time out between each made up scan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use another window form to wait for the input. This form can have a timer to check for timeout. When the timer expires, or when the user provides input, the new form will call a callback in the main form to inform it of the new info.